# Issue using wildcards in index with multiple start points

Tags: lucene, indexing, neo4j, wildcard, cypher

With multiple start points, if i provide the full name (value) of the key 'Name' the cypher query works.

This Works:

```
start n=node:na('NAME:("JERI, MICHAEL M", "ANDREW, TONNA", "JILLSO, DAVID")')
return n.NAME
```

Say, if i wish to use wildcards on Name key, something like this:

```
start n=node:na('NAME:("JERI*", "ANDREW*", "JILLSO*")')
return n.NAME
```

This doesn't work. It gives me **zero** rows.

It would be great if someone could help me with the correct way to achieve this.

Answer (score 2):

I think this may be due to the double quotes, making [Lucene query parser 3.6.2](http://lucene.apache.org/core/3_6_2/queryparsersyntax.html) (used in Neo4j 1.9) parse the terms as phrases instead of single terms. And wildcards are only supported for single terms, not phrases.